# How to dissociate all products from a specific category programmaticaly : Magento2

Tags: magento2, database

How to dissociate all the products from a specific category through code ?
I have the category id. I need to take all the products, out  of this category id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an object of the class `\Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryLinkRepositoryInterface` using the dependency injection and access the method `deleteByIds()`, passing two arguments,`Category Id` and `Product Sku`, like `deleteByIds($catId, $product->getSku())`